# Does ZMQ compress messages?

Tags: java, zeromq, jzmq

I'm interested in finding out if ZMQ already compresses messages before sending them out so as to not do this myself which would be redundant to compress a message twice.

If it does do this is it automatic, or is there an option param to specify?

I'm using java but it really doesn't matter I guess for libzmq it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ZMQ is not performing any serialization.
You can send messages via socket as String or byte[].
See example here: http://zguide.zeromq.org/java:wuserver

```
publisher.send(update, 0);
```

where update is String.

In general I recommend guide here http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all

Comment: +1 for the example which I've used many times! but the question is does .send(string) internally compress the message before "placing" it on the socket?

Comment: I think that under the hood send(String) invokes this method http://zeromq.github.io/jzmq/javadocs/org/zeromq/ZMQ.Socket.html#send(byte[], int)

Comment: message is not compressed

Answer (score 2):

OK so based on the help by [Szymon Wlodarczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4623946/szymon-w%C5%82odarczyk) I've managed to solve this by first going to the docs [enter link description here](http://zeromq.github.io/jzmq/javadocs/org/zeromq/ZMQ.Socket.html#send(byte%5B%5D,%20int)) and then moving on to [jeromq](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq) (which is a pure java implementation of jmq) and specifically follow the trace: [SocketBase](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq/blob/master/src/main/java/zmq/SocketBase.java) > [Pub](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq/blob/master/src/main/java/zmq/Pub.java) > [XPub](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq/blob/master/src/main/java/zmq/XPub.java) > [Dist](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq/blob/master/src/main/java/zmq/Dist.java) you'll find out that there is no compression.